# php use function to change a value of a variable outside function

Tags: php, function, variables

Im trying to change the value of a declared variable which is outside the function in use of a function

```
<?php
$test = 1;
function addtest() {
    $test = $test + 1;
}
addtest();
echo $test;
?>
```

but it seems it couldn't. only variables declared as parameters in the function only work. is there a technique for this? thanks in advance

Comment: Can `addtest` be altered to accept arguments?

Comment: If it can be altered to accept `global $test;`, then it can be altered to accept arguments

Comment: presume you can add params to the function `addtest` , then what could be the good way to change the first initialized `$test` ?

Comment: By passing it to the function.

Comment: You need to declare $test global inside your function.  But you really don't want to write code that relies on global state, it's not considered a good practice.

Comment: Mind giving example @JayBlanchard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a contrived example or not, but in this case (as in most cases) it would be extremely bad form to use `global`.  Why not just return the results and assign the return value?

```
$test = 1;
function increment($val) {
    return $val + 1;
}
$test = increment($test);
echo $test;
```

This way, if you ever need to increment *any other* variable besides `$test`, you're done already.

If you need to change multiple values and have them returned, you can return an array and use PHP's [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to easily extract the contents:

```
function incrementMany($val1, $val2) {
    return array( $val1 + 1, $val2 + 1);
}
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;

list($test1, $test2) = incrementMany($test1, $test2);
echo $test1 . ', ' . $test2;
```

You can use [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to also accept a dynamic number of arguments and return a dynamic number of results as well.

Comment: now i have a new problem, seems my function has more than 1 parameters, and i need to change more than 1 variable outside of it.

Comment: you can always return an array, and use PHP's [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Answer (score 6):

Change the variable inside the function to a global -

```
function addtest() {
    global $test; 
    $test = $test + 1;
}
```

There are a lot of caveats to using global variables -

- your code will be harder to maintain over the long run because globals may have an undesired affect on future calculations where you might not be aware how the variable was manipulated.
- if you refactor the code and the function goes away it will be detrimental because every instance of $test is tightly coupled to the code.

Here is a slight improvement and doesn't require `global` -

```
$test = 1;
function addtest($variable) {
    $newValue = $variable + 1;
    return $newValue;
}

echo $test; // 1
$foo = addtest($test);
echo $foo; // 2
```

Now you haven't had to use a global and you have manipulated $test to your liking while assigning the new value to another variable.

Comment: is there something that's negative security-wise when using it?

Comment: Note also that `function add() {
    $test = $test + 1;
} function addTest() {$test = 1;
add();
echo $test; } addTest();` would fail.... `global` really means `global`

Comment: i wouldnt want that to happen, i hope there is a cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the `global` keyword.

```
<?php
$test = 1;
function addtest() {
    global $test;
    $test = $test + 1;
}
addtest();
echo $test; // 2
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this .

```
<?php 

function addTest(&$val){
  # Add this & and val will update var who call in from outside 
  $val += 1 ;
}

$test = 1;
addTest($test);
echo $test;

// 2 

$anyVar = 5;
addTest($anyVar);
echo $anyVar;

// 6
```